# "Ось" і "он" - у чому рiзниця?

Tags: семантика

***Ось воно шо!*** i ***Он воно шо!*** - є різниця? У чому?

А якщо ***"Он він лежить"*** і ***"Ось він лежить"***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ось і он(о)

Зі «Словника української мови» в 11 томах (виділення напівжирним моє):

- > [ось](http://sum.in.ua/s/osj), частка. 1. вказівна. Уживається при вказуванні на кого-, що-небудь **на близькій відстані** (часто супроводжуються жестом). <…>
- > [он](http://sum.in.ua/s/on), частка. 1. вказівна. Уживається при вказуванні на **що-небудь віддалене**. <…>

  > [оно́, онно́](http://sum.in.ua/s/ono). 1. частка вказівна, розмовне. Те саме, що он. <…>

Це лише перші значення (є й інші). Але мені здається, ці значення є ключовими (можливо, первинними) і вони певною мірою задають семантику цих слів в усіх значеннях. Тобто що в усіх чи принаймні в більшості значень *ось* має семантику близькості, а *он((н)о)* — семантику віддаленості. Звісно, коли ми не вказуємо пальцем на конкретний предмет, а маємо на увазі якесь абстрактне поняття, то різниця між близькістю і віддаленістю дещо розмивається або навіть зовсім зникає.

<sub>Я не дуже на цьому знаюся, але, здається, «Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах підтверджує мою думку, що *ось* від початку мало семантику близькості, а *от* — семантику віддаленості: *[ось](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=230)* є результатом злиття й редукції слів *о* і *се* («це»), тобто певною мірою пов'язане зі значенням «цей»; *[он](//ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=189)* походить від [праслов'янських **onъ/*ona/*ono*, що мало значення «він/вона/воно», «той/та/те», «той/та/те, що там»](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/on%D1%8A) (а *[онно́, оно́](//ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=192)* є результатом злиття *он* з іншими словами), тобто певною мірою пов'язане (пов'язані) зі значенням «той».</sub>

#### «Ось воно що/як!» і «он(о) воно що/як!» (і «от воно що/як!»)

У «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 10:

- [«он((н)о) воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D0%BD(%D0%BD?%D0%BE)?%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 1431:

  - [«он воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D0%BD%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 1428,
  - [«оно воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 3,
  - [«онно воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 0;
- [«ось воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 562;
- [«от(о) воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE?%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 139 (про *от* і *ото* трішки пізніше):

  - [«от воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D1%82%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 139,
  - [«ото воно що/як»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22(?i)%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%22+%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+%22%D1%89%D0%BE%7C%D1%8F%D0%BA%22) — 0.

Тобто явну перевагу в цьому випадку начебто має частка з семантикою віддаленості. Цікаво, що в російській мові ситуація начебто протилежна: [«(в)от оно что/как»](//processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?api=1.0&mode=main&text=lexgramm&lex1=%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%22%7C%22%D0%BE%D1%82%22&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%22%7C%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%22) має істотну перевагу над [«(в)он оно что/как»](//processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?api=1.0&mode=main&text=lexgramm&lex1=%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%22%7C%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%22&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%22%7C%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%22) (1220 проти 158). З цього я можу спробувати зробити два різні висновки: або (а) для цього виразу близькість/віддаленість вже майже не має ваги (і говорять просто так, як склалося; або ж інші чинники, наприклад милозвучність чи швидкість вимовляння, впливають ще більше); або ж (б) семантична різниця між українськими *ось* і *он(о)* все-таки не зовсім така сама, як між російськими *вот* і *вон* (хоча в російській на перший погляд начебто ті самі [близькість і віддаленість](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2015/materials/pdf/KrylovaTV.pdf), але завжди можуть бути якісь нюанси, непомітні на перший погляд; зокрема мене трішки дивує етимологія українських *от*, *ото* і російського *вот*, про це нижче). Який з цих висновків ближче до істини, я гадки не маю.

#### <sub>Додатково: от, ото</sub>

<sub>Окрім частки з явною семантикою близькості *ось* і частки з явною семантикою віддаленості *он(о)*, українська мова ще має частку *от(о)*, з якою ситуація для мене не зовсім очевидна.</sub>

<sub>З одного боку, тлумачний словник каже, що *от* у першому значенні теж має семантику близькості (але про *ото́* вже такого не каже; на відміну від *он(н)о* і *он*, *ото* подано не просто посиланням на *от*, а окремою статтею):</sub>

> <sub>[от](http://sum.in.ua/s/ot), частка. 1. вказівна. Уживається при вказуванні на кого-, що-небудь **на близькій відстані** (часто супроводжується жестом); ось. <…></sub>

> <sub>[ото́](http://sum.in.ua/s/oto), частка, розмовне. 1. вказівна. Уживається при вказуванні на кого-, що-небудь (іноді супроводжуються вказівним жестом); ось то. <…></sub>

<sub>З іншого — етимологічний словник каже, що *[о́то́](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=234)* є результатом злиття *о* і *то* («те»), а *[от](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=231)* (як, до речі, і російське *вот*) є результатом видозміни *ото*. Тобто виходить, що за походженням ці частки начебто мали б мати семантику віддаленості — чи принаймні, здається, *ото* спочатку її мало (та й зараз в мене особисто *ото́* асоціюється радше з віддаленістю). Чи справді *от* змінило свою семантику на протилежну, ставши синонімом *ось* (а *ото* зупинилося десь на півдорозі) — чи, можливо, в українському *от* все-таки залишилися якісь нотки віддаленості (мовляв, *от* — це близько, але все-таки трішки далі, ніж *ось* [якщо так — на яку українську частку тоді семантично більш схоже російське *вот*: на *ось* чи на *от*?]) — я не знаю.</sub>

Comment: Ось/Он воно шо - це "близькій відстані" або "віддалене"?!

Comment: @behemothus, ну, на мою думку — виходить, що так (принаймні початкові значення слів; звісно, коли ми не вказуємо пальцем на конкретний предмет, а маємо на увазі якесь абстрактне поняття, то різниця між «цей, тут» і «той, там» дещо розмивається або навіть зовсім зникає, тому конкретно між «ось воно що!» й «он воно що!», я думаю, різниці майже ніякої).

Comment: @behemothus, [отут](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2015/materials/pdf/KrylovaTV.pdf) **цікавезна** стаття про різницю між російськими _вот_ і _вон_ (можливо, певною мірою це схоже на різницю між _ось_ і _он_, хоча навряд відповідність буде стовідсотковою). Там зокрема кажуть про «метафоризацію ідеї просторової близькості» («близькість до моменту мовлення», «часову близькість», «взаємну обумовленість») і «метафоризацію ідеї віддаленості» — тобто знов-таки близькість/віддаленість. Але, на жаль, не маю зараз часу заглиблюватися в це (ані щодо української, ані щодо російської).

Comment: aгa, дякую за посилання на Крилову. Вона тьотка вумна.)))  . Я вже поставiв це запитання на росiйскомовном ))  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463183

Comment: Спочатку я думав, що питання суто про «ось» і «он» загалом (а «ось воно що!» і «он воно що!» — це лише 1 з прикладів). Зараз зрозумів, що питання значною мірою фокусується саме на «ось воно що!» і «он воно що!» — тому переробив відповідь. (Також додав про «от», що етимологічно відповідає російському «вот», але семантично на «шкалі близькості-віддаленності», можливо, й не зовсім збігається з «ось».)

Comment: *Спочатку я думав, що питання суто про «ось» і «он»* -ви правильно думали, так і є. ))) Мене все цікаво ...